# Using Drag and Drop method

Tags: hp-uft

I have a Web-table that has Row and Column. Some Row has 8 cells some has 10, 14, and 20, 4,2. Some Row has no data, some row has few. First I have to identify there is at least 6 or 8 source object(balls) is present (imagine they are connected each other so one drag will pull all of them) in a row for drag  and then need to identify Row (target object) where empty cells is present(at least 6 to 8 or more) to drop the balls(data).and then do drag and drop.

First I tried to use object SPY to get the record in object repository then write the script

```
Browser("...").Page("...").WebTable("...")
```

I tried so many way like x,y combination for drag and drop also tried as WeElement none of them is worked out.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show some Examples what you have tried?

Comment: strTableName = "STORAGE TRACKS"
   
   'Set oTable = Browser("......").Page("...").WebTable("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=STT")
   
   'nRow=oTable.GetRoProperty("rows")
   
   'nCol=oTable.GetRoProperty("cols")
   
   'For j = 1 To nRow
   
    'CellValue=oTable.GetCellData(j,2)
    
    'msgbox CellValue
    
    'Next
'End if
'Next

Comment: Note: By using above code, I found there is 21 Cellvalue (Row) in the table. Some cellvalue has data and some are not or empty. I think I have to use this Cellvalue to find the source object (row that has 6 or 8 balls) to drag and Cellvalue to find the target object (row that has empty cell  6 or 8 balls to drop). But not sure the appropriate code.

Comment: Thanks Jonas for responding. Please see my comment

Comment: its really hard to understand what you want. But I would try to identify each cell you need using an webelement and then use the Drag/Drop Method

Comment: Sorry for that. lets try once again, first, need to identify, if there is a ROW in the table that has at least 6 balls available to pick up(balls are attach each other, so pull one ball will take all). when first condition is true, then need to search, if there is any ROW that has at least 6 empty space to drop the balls, and then, if the second condition is true,  then do drag the balls and drop them into the empty space. Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks in advanced Jonas

Comment: Jonas- Have you get any update. I really need support